# How can I exclude a class from my jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$(":input[type='text']").wijtextbox();
```

What I would like is for the wijtextbox() NOT to be applied if the class of my textbox is native. Is there a way I can somehow exclude this by adding to the above selector?

Make this a wijtextbox:

```
<textarea class="wijmo-wijtextbox ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all valid" >xx</textarea>
```

Don't make this a wijtextbox:

```
<textarea class="native wijmo-wijtextbox ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all valid" >xx</textarea>
```

Comment: If the class is the text "native?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This:

```
$("input[type='text']").not(".native").wijtextbox();
```

or this:

```
$("input[type='text']:not('.native')").wijtextbox();
```

should do the trick. There's also a shortcut for selecting an input whose type is `text`:

```
$("input:text").not(".native").wijtextbox();
```

More on `not()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

**EDIT:** Since it appears you need to select a textarea, try the following:

```
$("textarea").not(".native").wijtextbox();
```

Comment: `input:text` will not select a `textarea` which is what OP have in question.

Comment: Neither would `input[type='text']` have...he edited his question. :P

Comment: do not miss this useful pseudo selector sample : $( "li" ).not( ":even" ).css( "background-color", "red" )

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
$(":input:not(.native)").wijtextbox();
```

Since you selecting `textarea` you can even use this

```
$("textarea:not(.native)").wijtextbox();
```

`:not(selector)` - Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's `.not()` selector, as documented here: http://api.jquery.com/not/

How you would use it would really depend on what specifically you're trying to find though.