# How to exclude specific class names in querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript

How can I exclude tag elements that have a specific class name?

```
<span class="test" />
<span class="test asd" />

document.querySelectorAll('span.test'); //how to exclude all spans with "asd" as class name?
```

Comment: $('span:not(.asd)') - This will help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I exclude a class from my jQuery selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287621/how-can-i-exclude-a-class-from-my-jquery-selector)

Comment: @membersound [So you finally went for `querySelectorAll`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604825/how-to-get-only-specific-tags-of-elementsbyclassname/25604851#25604851)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) CSS pseudo-class:

```
document.querySelectorAll('span.test:not(.asd)');
```

Answer (score 27):

Use the [CSS's negation pseudo-selector, `:not()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

```
document.querySelectorAll('span.test:not(.asd)');
```

> The negation pseudo-class, `:not(X)`, is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

Comment: What if `.asd` is a parent class? E.g. if we need to select some elements with class `.bbb` that do not have `.asd` in some parent class? Is it possible to use `:not()` that way? Or should we first select all elements with class `.test` and without class `.asd`, and then somehow extract from that resulting NodeList elements with class `.bbb`? If so, then how? :)

Answer (score 5):

Element by tagName and ignore or exclude element that have a specific class:

```
document.querySelectorAll(`svg,div:not([class*="background"]`)
```