# Exclude all text type inputs from querySelectorAll("input")

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following setup where a custom checkmark is added to style the radio buttons. 
but it also adds that checkmark to the text type inputs.

```js
var changed =function(){

    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table")).forEach((element,index) =>
    {
      Array.from(element.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach((myinp,index) =>
      {

              if(myinp.checked==true){
                   myinp.parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("active");
              }else{
                  myinp.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("active");
              }

      });
    });  
}//changed function ends

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("table")).forEach((element,index) =>
{
    Array.from(element.querySelectorAll("input")).forEach((myinp,index) =>
    {
       var checkmark = document.createElement("span");
       checkmark.classList.add("checkmark");
       myinp.parentNode.appendChild(checkmark);
       myinp.addEventListener("change", changed);
    });
});
```

```css
table tbody tr td:first-child{
position:relative;
}
.confirmit-table tbody tr input[type='radio'][type='checkbox']{
visibility:hidden
}


 /*Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark,.dotmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
input[type='text']{
  width:20px;
}
/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
table tbody tr:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
table tbody tr:hover input ~ .dotmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
table tbody tr input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color:#11448d;
}
/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
table tbody tr input:checked ~ .dotmark  {
  background-color:#11448d;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after,.dotmark:after  {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top:50%;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
table tbody tr input:checked ~ .checkmark:after{
  display: block;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
table tbody tr input:checked ~ .dotmark:after{
  display: block;
}
    
    
/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
table tbody tr .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 30%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
table tbody tr .dotmark:after {
    left: 8px;
    top: 8px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color:#fff;  
}

/*Custom check boxes/radio buttons*/
table label {
  width:350px;
  display:block;
  margin:0px;
  padding:5px 10px;
} 
table label:hover{
margin:0px;
}


  
.confirmit-table tbody tr{
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
.active{
  background:#6081b9 !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id='txt1' type='text' name='test'>
     
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for='txt1'>Text Input1</label> 
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id='txt2' type='text' name='test'>
     
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for='txt2'>Text input 2</label> 
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id='inp1' type='radio' name='test'>
     
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for='inp1'>Radio button 1</label> 
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id='inp2' type='radio' name='test'>
      
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for='inp2'>Radio button 2</label> 
    </td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id='inp3' type='radio' name='test'>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for='inp3'>Radio button 3</label> 
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have used the javascript to style(i.e custom checkmark element added next to radio type inputs) the radio buttons, but i do not want this styling to apply text type inputs in javascript only.

How do I exclude the text type inputs from querySelectorAll("input")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude specific class names in querySelectorAll()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25605367/how-to-exclude-specific-class-names-in-queryselectorall)

Answer (score 5):

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type=text])'));
```

Comment: Actually OP only wants radio buttons.

Comment: that worked, @connexo i just wants to exclude the text inputs. i have same styling for checkboxes also.  thank you so much.

Comment: This is not a good solutiion. What about `input type=date`, `input type=password`, `input type=email` etc etc? Don't use excluding selectors if you don't have to. You are bound to create problems in the future, even if currently your website doesn't have any of those inputs. Instead, use `element.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]")`.

Comment: Won't work for input without a `type` attribute or with an invalid one (even though their `type` IDL will be "text". https://jsfiddle.net/nfogLqe1/

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
element.querySelectorAll("input")
```

to

```
element.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")
```

to only get the radio buttons.

If you also want checkboxes:

```
element.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox]")
```

To exclude a certain type by an attribute **present**, you can use

```
element.querySelectorAll("input:not([type=text])")
```

Note that `text` is also the default type, so the attribute might be omitted. To make sure, you could convert the `NodeList` to an `Array` and apply a `filter`:

```
[...element.querySelectorAll('input')].filter(el -> el.type !== 'text')
```

In your case, the safest bet probably is a positive filter approach:

```
[...element.querySelectorAll('input')].filter(el -> ['checkbox', 'radio'].includes(el.type))
```